# Jquery load specific item by name or id

Tags: jquery, load

I tried to load a specific item but I couldn't do it.

This is my script it works fine but I want to load a specific item covered with a "name" or "id"

```
 <input id="qs" type="text">
<input type="button" id="submit"> 
 <div id="load1"></div>
        <script type="text/JavaScript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#submt").click(function(){
        var tag=$("#qs").val();
        tag=tag.replace(/ /ig,'\+');
        var tz="search.xhtml?get-search=";
        var url=tz+tag;
                $("#div1").load(url);
            });
        });
        </script>
```

this script loads the whole page of **Search.xhtml**

I only want to load item covered or warped with `<div name="suggest"> or <div id="suggest"`

Answer (score 0):

You can try just by doing as :

```
$("#div1").load(url #suggest);
```

where the target can be the id of container you want to load.